# How to replace value for a key in a json file using ansible

Tags: ansible

Below is my `sample.json` file

```
 "abc": {
                "host": "xyz",
                "version": "3.0.0-4"
        },
 "def": {               
                "host": "xyz",
                "version": "3.0.0-4"
        },
 "ghi": {
                "host": "xyz",
                "version": "4.1.0-4"
        },
```

How to modify value of version key for some of the blocks and not modify for other blocks?
For eg. in above case I want to modify version value for abc and def block but not for ghi block using ansible.

Expected o/p :

```
 "abc": {
                "host": "xyz",
                "version": "4.0.0-4"  // modified value
        },
 "def": {               
                "host": "xyz",
                "version": "4.0.0-4"  // modified value
        },
 "ghi": {
                "host": "xyz",
                "version": "4.1.0-4"  //not modified
        },
```

Comment: What is the logic? Update *abc* and *def* only? Or, update lower versions only?

Answer (score 2):

- Read the JSON data into a dictionary. For example,

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: sample.json
        name: sample
```

gives

```yaml
  sample:
    abc:
      host: xyz
      version: 3.0.0-4
    def:
      host: xyz
      version: 3.0.0-4
    ghi:
      host: xyz
      version: 4.1.0-4
```

- To change the version of items *abc* and *def* some structure is needed. For example, let's create a dictionary of the new versions

```yaml
  new_version:
    abc: 4.0.0-4
    def: 4.0.0-4
```

Then the task below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        sample: "{{ sample|
                    combine({item.key: item.value|
                    combine({'version': new_version[item.key]})}) }}"
      loop: "{{ sample|dict2items }}"
      when: item.key in new_version
      vars:
        new_version:
          abc: 4.0.0-4
          def: 4.0.0-4
```

gives

```yaml
  sample:
    abc:
      host: xyz
      version: 4.0.0-4
    def:
      host: xyz
      version: 4.0.0-4
    ghi:
      host: xyz
      version: 4.1.0-4
```

---

Note: It is not necessary to iterate *set_fact*. Instead, create the dictionary

```yaml
  update: "{{ new_version|
              dict2items|
              json_query('[].{key: key, value: {version: value}}')|
              items2dict }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  update:
    abc:
      version: 4.0.0-4
    def:
      version: 4.0.0-4
```

Then, recursively combine the dictionaries

```yaml
  sample_update: "{{ sample|combine(update, recursive=true) }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  sample_update:
    abc:
      host: xyz
      version: 4.0.0-4
    def:
      host: xyz
      version: 4.0.0-4
    ghi:
      host: xyz
      version: 4.1.0-4
```

---

- The logic of the task might be different. For example "Change the lower versions only". In this case, the data and code are simpler, e.g.

```yaml
        new_version: "4.0.0-4"
```

The task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        sample: "{{ sample|combine({item.key: item.value|
                           combine({'version': new_version})}) }}"
      loop: "{{ sample|dict2items }}"
      when: item.value.version is version(new_version, 'lt')
      vars:
        new_version: "4.0.0-4"
```

---

Then, replace the file, e.g.

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: sample.json
        content: "{{ sample|to_json }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat sample.json
```

> {"abc": {"host": "xyz", "version": "4.0.0-4"}, "def": {"host": "xyz", "version": "4.0.0-4"}, "ghi": {"host": "xyz", "version": "4.1.0-4"}}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small function which takes as arguments:

- obj: Json object
- keys: Array of keys affected
- prop: The property to be changed
- value: The new value of the property

```js
let myObj = {
  "abc": { "host": "xyz", "version": "3.0.0-4" }, 
  "def": { "host": "xyz", "version": "3.0.0-4" }, 
  "ghi": { "host": "xyz", "version": "4.1.0-4" }
}


const repla = (obj, keys, prop, value) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
    if(keys.indexOf(key) > -1) {
      return {[key]: {...obj[key], [prop] : value}}
    } else {
      return {[key] : obj[key]};
    }
  })
}

const newObj = repla(myObj, ["abc", "def"], "version", "newData");
console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am trying to achieve this using ansible .